# How to use AngularJS to get JSON from external URL and display in page - Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: html, json, angularjs, url, jsonp

I am trying to make an http call to a URL to get a JSON and display this on my page.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{"ticker":{"high":484.01099,"low":470.37201,"avg":477.1915,"vol":2193393.03322,"vol_cur":4588.62668,"last":482.16,"buy":482.16,"sell":481.2,"updated":1398350394,"server_time":1398350394}}
```

The code is included below. I read that I have to use 'JSONP' to but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

```
<html ng-app>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <div id = "content" style="min-width: 1200px; max-width: 90%: margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <div style="width: 520px; float: left;">
                <h4>Bot Summary:</h4>
            </div>
            <div  ng-controller="TickerControl" style="width: 680px; float: left;">
                <h4>Market Summary</h4>
                <p>Price = {{data}} </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function TickerControl($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
                $scope.method = 'JSONP';
                $scope.url = 'https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

                $scope.getTicker = function() {
                  $scope.code = null;
                  $scope.response = null;

                  $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url, cache: $templateCache}).
                    success(function(data, status) {
                      $scope.status = status;
                      $scope.data = data;
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status) {
                      $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
                      $scope.status = status;
                  });
                };

                            $scope.getTicker();
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

I have now modified my code to try and do JSONP requests. I am getting the following error:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker?callback=angular.callbacks._0". angular.js:8582
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ticker:1
```

I seem to be getting text back. Since I cannot control the server response, how can I parse this text to JSON... or just even display it... It's available to view in the chrome dev environment.

**UPDATE 2**

Apparently this seems to be an issue with the server not being configured properly. Since I don't have access to it, it would be nice to be able to just receive text and parse it in the client!

Comment: unless your code is on `btc-e.com` aswell you need to either use `JSONP` or `crossorigin AJAX`

Comment: Hi @Valerji, thanks this is what I am understanding. But I am unsure how to use JSONP, i tried to do some stuff with adding 'callback' in the URL but I got other errors.

Comment: well the server seem not to serve `JSONP` i think you try to acess some private apis, whatever, your only solution seem to crealte a 'proxy' script on your website or use a service like corsproxy.com (not affiliated)

Comment: This `<p>Price = {{getTicker()}} </p>` is making continuous calls to a method that connects to the api, thats why it hangs, its like an infinite loop

Comment: @TimCastelijns, what would I have to do so that it makes the call only on first page load? (Note: in the future i would like this to update continously, say every 5-10 sec)

Comment: Do `$scope.getTicker()` at the end of your controller code, that executes ones, when the controller is 'instantiated'

Comment: @TimCastelijns inside the function TickerControl(){} ?

Comment: @ArmenSafieh-Garabedian no below the function $scope.updateModel()

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanks that's what I meant sorry. Still makes multiple calls though :(

Comment: Did you remove `<p>Price = {{getTicker()}} </p>` though

Comment: @TimCastelijns oh sorry, im such a noob. How will it know where to put the response though?

Comment: You could do `<p>Price = {{data}} </p>` or something similar instead, so it loads some data from the scope instead of calling the function over and over

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanks man this works now so i get a reasonable error message. Updates in post.

Comment: Guys any ideas with updates? This is driving me nuts! @TimCastelijns

Comment: Is the server configured to return application/json as content-type?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I don't know and I don't think I can find out unless it's possible to do this from the response? If it's not what can I do?

Comment: Yes its in the response headers. I checked, the content type is `text/html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some more research and experimenting with different methods, I regret to inform you that what you're trying to achieve cannot be done.

I sent a GET request to `https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker?callback=JSON_CALLBACK` for testing purposes and in the response headers it says

> content-type → text/html; charset=utf-8

Because you do cross domain calls and you have no access to the server, you have to use jsonp. But jsonp does not work with `text/html` content. This related to the error

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html

So even though the response looks like valid JSON, it is not treated as such by your client application.

To solve this you would have to add the proper Content-Type header on the server, but you have no access to it.

Quote from [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239015/send-request-as-jsonp-interpret-response-as-text-using-jquery-1-5):

> jsonp can only be used if and when the server properly embed the response in a javascript function call.

---

To sum it up:

You should either

- allow cross domain calls by configuring the server to do so
- send back the proper content-type header by configuring the server to do so

Sadly you have no access to the server.

Be aware that this is not your fault. It is because the server is not configured properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim. So it's not possible to just get text and parse it in the client? :O

Comment: No, because jsonp expects different content than `text/html`

Comment: That's a shame. I'm going to have to run my own .net server that can get and parse the JSONs and make request to it!

Answer (score 0):

If the response contains plain text you can parse it using "angular.fromJson(data)". Use a GET-request to fetch the data (and make sure the response does not actually contain HTML code).

Comment: Well its supposed to be JSON, I dont know why im getting that error message. How can i just print the response to console?

Comment: even if you "GET" the data?
You could also try to set the Content-Type explicitly, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http for details

Comment: GET doesn't work at all because of "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. "

Comment: Well, you _could_ try to force the Content-type of the JSONP request to text/html, but this is kind of ugly..

Comment: I'm willing to try anything at this stage!

Comment: Look at the "Setting HTTP Headers" section of the angular $http documentation on how to do that.