# How in the world sessions works in Flash/Air inside flash cs6 environment (no inside a browser)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, session-state, amfphp, urlloader

I understand that sessions in a browsers works by either the cookie, url or other browser->server protocol exchange...

From other answers in this post and related links this can be understood.

[Does Flash Player transmit session cookies automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161401/does-flash-player-transmit-session-cookies-automatically)

However, when using an flash/air movie inside flash cs6 (or just air stand alone), neither of this run inside a browser.

So I believe (according to answers) that it should use some user agent to create this match up between client and server.

A good example in our program is that running inside the CS6 environment we are able to modify a $_session variable in php using URLLOADER.

By other side, later, the same $_session is modified this time using AMF-PHP framework, obtaining and changing the values previously set.

So, is anyway to see this initial matching in this case? between the debuggin cs6 movie and the server, maybe using Charles proxy?

What do you recommend?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Flash Player transmit session cookies automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161401/does-flash-player-transmit-session-cookies-automatically)

Comment: Nop, I read the link, please check the edit.

Comment: You should edit your question and try to rephrase it in a way that reflects all of the answers/comments made here. I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. In the end, why does it matter which user agent AIR uses to make HTTP requests? As long as that user agent behaves as expected (which was always my experience), why does it matter what the user agent is? The choice of which user agent to use was a proprietary decision made by Adobe engineers. Either you are facing a specific problem with that, or you're just asking for conjecture type responses ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't know that the "how" of things does not matter ;-)

I will rephrase as you suggestion.

Comment: AIR runtime uses default browser for settings and cache - Safari for Mac, and Internet Explorer on PC.

Comment: And Flash inside cs6 ?
Could you provide a link
Thanks

Comment: From Flash when you run such as by ctrl+enter you're running in a projector; otherwise, you need to publish a build.

Comment: May I be able of checking how the matching of this values (client-server) is being done using charles proxy or other software, when running a projector?

Thanks a lot for your contribution.

Comment: @voskyc Use Fiddler to inspect HTTP traffic between the Flash player and your server.

Answer (score 2):

Flash sends HTTP requests through the browser so if there are cookies set for the current session, those will travel with the requests.

Here is an [SO question / answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161401/does-flash-player-transmit-session-cookies-automatically) with more detail.

Comment: Sorry I didn't write this down before, but my concern is that Im using using the movie debugging in cs6 not inside any browser (the same with AIR), I can do the same via air debugging in cs6 or air stand-alone.

So, assuming it is via "the browser", which browser?, which user agent?

That is my doubt, I understand browser case, but in this case?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: (I've red the link, the TS have the same doubt in the comments section, no response to explain how works in my case however o.O ).

Comment: @voskyc You can try running Fiddler to capture requests fired by Flash inside CS6 and look at the request headers. I don't have Flash installed anymore so I can't test.