# How does secure authentication work in a web application

Tags: security, ssl

I understand how ssl works, so the browser sends the username/password encrypted. But what happens next ?

Does the client receive a cookie ? Is it secure ? How does the server-browser communicate safely if the only https page is the login page ?

I think if someone get's a copy of that cookie when it's being sent, they can acces that account, no matter how encrypted is the cookie

Actually I want to understand the process from login to logout in a secure web application.

Server: Tomcat, Apache ...
Platform: java, php, ...

Thank you

Comment: How do you define "security"? Every web developer out there will tell you *their* setup is secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Episode 195 of the security now podcast deals with this topic in some depth. http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm
You can either scan the transcript (which I would recommend to do first in order to find out, wether it answers your questions) or listen to the whole episode.

Comment: This is a great PodCast on SSL/TLS security.  It does not, however, address http session management for non-https pages.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else trips onto this:  I found this Wikipedia article on [Session Fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation) and this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661599/login-session-cookies-ajax-and-security) very useful in answering this question, than the 90+ minute podcast from GRC (noted above) that is mostly related to SSL/TLS.