# Sending POST, GET and COOKIE data with AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, cookies, request

The POST and GET data are done very easily with ajax. I can't find a way to 'include' a cookie. How can I include a 'cookie'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery ajax call not sending cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911710/jquery-ajax-call-not-sending-cookie)

Comment: Or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to explicitly add a cookie to an XMLHttpRequest request (or for any of the other techniques used for Ajax). The [`setRequestHeader` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#dom-xmlhttprequest-setrequestheader) explicitly forbids setting cookies.

You need to add a cookie through the normal methods (i.e. via the HTTP `Set-Cookie` *response* header and the JS `document.cookie` API) and then make the request.

You'll also need to set `xml.withCredentials = true;` for a cross-origin request (and the cookie will need to belong to the host you are making the request to, not the document hosting the JS making the request).