# jquery.post doesn't create a session

Tags: php, ajax, session, jquery

I hava a strange problem. I'm using jquery `$.post()` to send/recieve vars from a `PHP` script.

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#r_submit").click(function()
{
    $.post("http://" + server + "/msws/", 
    {
        action: "register",
        sub_action: "register_validate"
    },
    function(json) 
    {
        json = $.parseJSON(json);
        alert(json.cell_is_good);
    });
});
```

**PHP**:

http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=S7zDD

**Problem:**

If I run the code on my pc **(WAMP)** it works fine,
but if I upload it to my server **(justhost)** then it dosn't keep the session
if I alert the session when I create it, it is there, but when I try to get the session 
later, it's gone,
I think it has to do with the fact that the server thinks that the browser was closed, so it destroys the session?
Thank you :)

Comment: I know this problem from chrome.

Comment: Is the post made on the same server?

Comment: Is `server` in your JavaScript code the same as the domain of your PHP page?

Comment: race condition?  http://www.chipmunkninja.com/Troubles-with-Asynchronous-Ajax-Requests-g@

Comment: Can you confirm that the cookie is set in firebug?

Comment: tommy, yes.
ficuscr, i am looking in the link, thank you.
rekire, I'm using chrome, and the session cookie is created.

Answer (score 2):

You are starting your session without a session id. For this to work your PHP has to be configured to use [transparent session id](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid), which is deactivated by default. So you will have to start the session in the script that has the AJAX-call, and submit the `session_id()` in the POST request, and start the session in your PHP something like this:

```
if (!isset($_POST['SID'])) {
    die('{}');
}
session_start($_POST['SID']);
```

Also I would leave out the host-part of the url you are calling in your `$.post` to avoid cross-domain ajax call problems (also this most likely will not fix your problem). It will work only on the same server, so you can write the ajax call like this:

```
$.post("/msws/", //...
```

Comment: I do no think this is the issue.  Cookies are sent with ajax request.  @rekire asked a good question that has not been answered that would tell us if this is the case or not.  Chrome has developer tools too, press F12.

Comment: The javascript is seprate it is a mobile app, it is not on the server

Comment: Where else would the client side JS be...?  All the more reason to inspect the request.  Though still not sure how that fits if you say it worked locally.

Comment: OK - you said you are seeing the session in the header.  Then this answer is probably not your solution.  Maybe explore the path scope comments (cross domain).  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041285/does-jquery-send-cookies-in-a-post

Answer (score 0):

check if you have multiple session cookies.

i've the same situation with codeigniter and i found that every new page creates its own session

Comment: yes it was working fine in my local machine too. 
do u work on sub domain
could you send your url?

Comment: Still sounds like classic race condition to me.  dj_boy, did that article make sense?