# Will http_only cookies be sent with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cookies, httponly

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972/how-do-httponly-cookies-work-with-ajax-requests)

But at the bottom it says **This information is likely no longer up to date.**
So my question is, will http_only cookies be sent with AJAX? Can the response via AJAX set http_only cookies?

Edit 1: Let's say an user logged in to the system. His session started and http_only cookie is set. He tries to fetch list of his friends via AJAX and sends JSON. When making the AJAX request, do I need to make anything special to say to send cookies or not? Will each request send the cookies to the server by default? Will the response send back cookies (let's say I am updating users' time for last activity)?

Comment: you need to set the `withCredentials` option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they will.

The `HttpOnly` makes cookies not appear in `document.cookie` and `XMLHTTPRequest.getAllResponseHeaders`. It doesn't prevent them from being sent with HTTP requests, **with the exception** of cross-domain HTTP requests (which it doesn't sound like you're using here).